# What does 'constitution' mean in this line from False Disposition?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The chorus of False Disposition begins with this line:

> When a boyish **constitution** gets to lead the revolution, everything about this seems a bad idea

The definitions I have found for 'constitution' mean either: some sort of document or rules, or an attribute possessed by a person or thing. Neither makes much sense in the given context

Is there another definition which fits this line better?

Comment: Please state where the quotation is from, date, author, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the second of the definitions you found. [According to M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constitution):

> the structure, composition, physical makeup, or nature of something

The "constitution" doesn't really lead the revolution, but it can be considered to represent a person who has such a constitution. (This could be considered an example of metonymy.) Of course, the following mention of a "revolution" hints at the word's other common meaning:

> the basic principles and laws of a nation, state, or social group that determine the powers and duties of the government and guarantee certain rights to the people in it

Caveat: I have no idea what "False Disposition" is and thus can't be sure of this interpretation. If you want a better answer, then you should really provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

"a boyish constitution" would simply mean characteristics that make boys boys.

Constitution can mean "the things something is made up of".

I don't think it would be quite correct to say its a synonym for "boy" as they used the word boyish, which means "boy like".

It may be useful to cite the first **2** lines of the chorus, which shows this is likely written in this style because constitution rhymes with revolution.

Per https://genius.com/Ferry-vocaloid-false-disposition-lyrics the first 2 lines of the chorus are:

```
So a boyish constitution
Gets to lead a revolution
```